# Symfony2 - Get the current URL or route in TWIG template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

My route is

```
admin:
      path:     /admin/
      defaults: { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Admin:admin }
```

How I can get route name in PHP template ?

Comment: I guess in twig you can use `app.request.attributes.get('_route')` for php template you can derive equivalent code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the current URL

[`$request->getRequestUri();`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getRequestUri) or `app.request.uri`

As for the route itself, the best practice is to inject it as parameter in your controller, see [the doc here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/routing.html#extra-parameters). You could use `$request->attributes->get('_route')` or `app.request.attributes.get('_route')` but it is not as reliable, for example it [won't work with forwards](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/854#issuecomment-10904110) as you are forwarding to a controller, not to a path. And it is really only [meant for debugging purposes according to Fabien (@fabpot), the creator](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/854#issuecomment-1123531), so I would not rely on it for future upgrades' sake.

**Sidenote**

Remember to [avoid `$request->get()`](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/3.0/Request.php#L707) anytime you can, so no `$request->get('_route')` as I've seen in some answers on similar questions

> If you don't need the flexibility in controllers, it is better to
>   explicitly get request parameters from the appropriate public property
>   instead (attributes, query, request)

The reason being that it will look in said public properties (attributes, query & request) instead of just the one (attributes), making it much slower

Comment: Use the RequestStack if possible: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Comment: Use the RequestStack if in a service. Request is the way to go for controllers.

Answer (score 7):

Not a good thing to do directly in Twig but you can still do. The better way is to pass it as an argument from the controller.

Get route parameters in Twig.

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') }}
```

AND

Gets whole bundle name in Twig.

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get("_controller") }}
```

Get route name in Twig.

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the Route Name in Symfony2 enter the following code snippet

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$routeName = $request->get('_route');
```

To get the URL in Symfony2,

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$routeURL = $request->getRequestUri();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding that in some cases, `app.request.uri` won't return the url of the current page.

Example: in your page template, you call a controller via:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:MyController:myBlock')) }}
```

And in `myBlockAction`, you render another template, say `block.html.twig`.

A call to `app.request.uri` from `block.html.twig` will display something like:

```
http://www.example.com/app.php/_fragment?_path=_format%3Dhtml%26_locale%3Dfr%26_controller%3DAppBundle%253AMyController%253AmyBlock
```

If you want to get the absolute url of the rendered page from inside `block.html.twig`, you can reassemble it from php $_SERVER variables:

```
{{ app.request.server.get('REQUEST_SCHEME') ~ '://' ~ 
   app.request.server.get('SERVER_NAME') ~ 
   app.request.server.get('PHP_SELF') }}
```

You can also add `QUERY_STRING` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

On symfony5 you can do this.

**Calling a controller block and passing current url:**

```
{{ render_esi(controller('App\\Controller\\Frontend\\BlockController::social',{'pageUri': app.request.uri })) }}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Frontend;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class BlockController extends AbstractController {
    public function social($pageUri) {
        return $this->render('block/_social.html.twig', ['pageUri' => $pageUri]);
    }

}
```

**Output twig:** *'block/_social.html.twig'*

```
<small>Current Url : {{ pageUri  }}</small>
```